# Controlling VirtualBox

Tags: python

Documentation for pyVB is given in http://enomalism.com/api/pyvb/

we are trying to make a commandline interface to virtualbox using pyvb module in python.

```
>>> import pyvb
>>> n=pyvb.vm.vbVM()
>>> n.setUUID("64e1b2e5-739e-45a6-b8d7-3ab7519c5215}")
>>> m=pyvb.vb.VB()
>>> m.startVM(n)
```

this is how we tried doing it, but vm doesn't get started.

Comment: is the trailing `}` needed in the UUID?

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel; VirtualBox already comes with [a command line interface](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html)?